# How to change DOM element in embedded iframe content?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

I have a situation where I must embed a legacy form inside a styled page using an iframe.

We redesigned our website to be beautiful, but we have to embed this ugly form on one of the pages.

Our beautiful website page ( beautiful.mycompany.com ) , contains an iframe like this :

```
 <iframe id="embedded-form" frameborder="0" height="240" scrolling="auto" src="http://ugly.mycompany.com/old/forms/hzxkardx.P_Select" width="320"></iframe>
```

The ugly form, on the same domain but a different subdomain ( ugly.mycompany.com ), looks like this, without any ID's in the elements.  I don't have access to change anything on the ugly page.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
     <head>
       <style type="text/css">
       @import url(http://ugly.mycompany.com/css/web_defaultapp.css);
       </style>
     </head>
     <body >
         <H2>Legacy Form Title</H2>
         <BR>
         <BR>
```

I'm trying to access the H2 on the embedded page using javascript and the DOM.

I was hoping to use something like this, but I don't understand how to navigate into the page inside the iframe :

```
  <script language="javascript" >
      document.querySelector("iframe > html > body > h2").style.backgroundColor = "red";
  </script>
```

Thanks for your help, I'm trying to use native javascript ( not jquery ).

Comment: Are you on the same sub domain?

Comment: different subdomains, same domain

Comment: Different sub-domains prevent access to the content of the iframe for security reasons. It is treated as a totally different domain.